# how to store label text in array from checkbox in vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to store name of label of selected checkbox in array.

```
<template>
<div class="q-gutter-sm">
              <q-checkbox dense v-model="add_info" label="Data Structures and Algorithms" color="teal" /><br />
              <q-checkbox dense v-model="add_info" label="High Level Design" color="teal" /><br />
              <q-checkbox dense v-model="add_info" label="Low Level Design" color="teal" /><br />
              <q-checkbox dense v-model="add_info" label="Development (Backend, Frontend, Fullstack)" color="teal" />
            </div>
</template>
```

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'


const add_info = ref([])

</srcipt>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works great

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const add_info = ref([])
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>array of checked labels {{ add_info }}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="add_info" value="coolLabel" />
    <label for="coolLabel">This is a cool label!</label>
  </div>
</template>
```

As [shown here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kU1PAyEQhv/KyKWadJd7Q5t49+hNjKG7s5a6fGRgV5vN/neBtWo1KSGBeXnngRkmdu99PQ7INkyEhrSPEDAOfietNt5RhAkIO5ihI2dglawraaVtnA0RVNu+aNs52GbT7dPznbSCL5xESEFE43sVMUdRtHpMG0hD+J0iUidwHTQHbN6whV7tsQ8wTT/ceRY8v6WkaOuHCPHkcStZSdq7D8lAt5fxWBnXYp/EMyeLqh9KnnP9Q74oafxMLjdD5+jSsHs86ABpKsjq8sAbwctacgVfShL8u1C2ZkvnKqN8fQzOpt5O2Sy/DoJkGyhK1lJHcyzZIUYfNpyHrsk/cgy1o1eedjUNNmqDNQZT7cm9B6QElmz9i8GTOCJVhLZFQrrG/GP9x83YWdqZzZ+V6bt9)

PS: you can also of course have `coolLabel` as another `ref` if you want to have it reusable.